# Css table transparency

Tags: css, transparency

Is it possible to make all of the content inside a table transparent on hover by using css- for example

```
<table><tr><td> AN IMAGE </td> <td> SOME TEXT </td></tr></table>
```

so if either the image or the text are hovered, both will become transparent? Again - by using ONLY css.

Comment: table:hover {visibility:hidden;}

Comment: table:hover { opacity: .5 } works but now i have another problem - they are all inside a fixed div, so when i hover they either disappear totally or nothing happens, based on what i put as the z-index - nothing helps.

Comment: @DejanBiljecki If your comment is meant to indicate the solution you've decided on, please mark that answer as accepted. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
table:hover { opacity: .5 }
```

... in case you you want to adjust how much transparency you want *(any value from 0 to 1)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
table:hover td { visibility: hidden; }
```